# python reference error in building trie tree

Tags: python

I want to build a trivial trie tree in python, and here is my code

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,ref={},num=0):
        self.ref = ref
        self.num = num

def makeTrie(node,s): 
    node.ref.setdefault(s[0],Node())
    if len(s) == 1:
        node.ref[s[0]].num += 1
        return
    makeTrie(node.ref[s[0]],s[1:])


trie = Node()
makeTrie(trie,'abcd')

print trie.ref['d'].num
print trie.ref['a'].ref['b'].ref['c'].ref['d'].num
```

And I am very confused,the statement `print trie.ref['d'].num` also have value!!
But I don't know when I insert 'd' in trie ? The code above does't just insert 'd' in `trie.ref['a'].ref['b'].ref['c']`

Comment: What is a **trie** tree? Just asking.

Comment: Trie tree is like that . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into a problem with [mutable default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument), I think.

In the initializer for `Node`, you have `ref={}`. But `{}` is a `dict` and hence a mutable object. As such, each call to `Node()` calls the initializer, which mutates the same `ref` dictionary.

Fix (I think):

```
class Node:
    #                      vvvv
    def __init__(self, ref=None, num=0):
        if ref is None: # <--
            ref = {} # <--
        self.ref = ref
        self.num = num

def makeTrie(node,s):
    node.ref.setdefault(s[0],Node())
    if len(s) == 1:
        node.ref[s[0]].num += 1
        return
    makeTrie(node.ref[s[0]],s[1:])

trie = Node()
makeTrie(trie,'abcd')

try:
    print(trie.ref['d'].num)
except KeyError:
    print('KeyError occurred!')
print(trie.ref['a'].ref['b'].ref['c'].ref['d'].num)
```

Result:

```
KeyError occurred!
1
```